# Mercurial (hg) not respecting default ACL settings

Tags: acl, mercurial

I'm trying to set fine grained access control to various mercurial repositories using ACL.  When I push changes to repository any new files created under `/myrepo/.hg/store/data` do not have default permissions and users can't access them.

The issue is reproducible.  Assume the user "myuser" is part of www-data group.  On the server:

```
hg init /tmp/test
chown root:root /tmp/test
chmod 770 /tmp/test
setfacl -Rdm g:www-data:rwx /tmp/test
setfacl -Rm g:www-data:rwx /tmp/test
```

On a windows box with TortoiseHg, set to use `plink.exe` for ssh with shared key:

```
hg clone ssh://myuser@servername//tmp/test test
#add file test1.txt and commit to test
hg push ssh://myuser@server//tmp/test
cd ..
hg clone ssh://myuser@servername//tmp/test test2  <---FAIL
```

Back on the server checking ACL

```
getfacl /tmp/test/.hg/store/data/test1.txt.i
# file: tmp/test/.hg/store/data/test1.txt.i
# owner: myuser
# group: myuser
user::rw-
group::rw-
other::r--
```

So the new file was not created with default permissions I added to parent folder `/tmp/test`. This problem also happens when you do `hg pull` on the server and `hg serve` on the client.

My `/etc/fstab` is mounting the partition with "default,acl" options.  Also `touch /tmp/test/test1` creates file with appropriate default permissions as expected

**Edit**

- Mercurial version: 2.0.2-1ubuntu1
- Linux Ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what's probably happening:

- You're creating a /tmp/test/.hg directory via 'hg init' presumably without group permissions due to a restrictive umask
- You're recursively setting ACLs, but not recursively setting traditional permission bits to match
- Mercurial **copies** the traditional permission bits on */tmp/test/.hg/* when creating new files under .hg
- Thus, newly added files have no group permissions
- By definition, this masks out any default ACL entries you've set

Fix: set proper traditional Unix permissions on your repository.

Comment: Just replace `chmod 770 /tmp/test` with `chmod -R g+rwX /tmp/test`

Answer (score 0):

I can no longer reproduce the error.  Looks like I messed up when setting up/conducting the test.